# Unable to build turtlebot3 package from source using catkin build

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, turtlebot3, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am currently running `ROS-melodic` on `Ubuntu 18.04`.

I cloned the repository (using the `git clone` command) from [source](https://github.com/ROBOTIS-GIT/turtlebot3/tree/melodic-devel) to `/home/catkin_ws/src` directory. Then, from inside the `catkin_ws` directory, I ran the command `catkin build turtlebot3`.

This is the [link](https://ideone.com/b0vvQ8) to the error message.

This is the [link](https://ideone.com/Rofsfo) to  `build.cmake.001.log` at `home/skpro19/catkin_ws/logs/turtlebot3_bringup/build.cmake.001.log` as mentioned in the above error message.

I understand that it has got something to do with the `CMakeLists.txt` file of some package. But I am not exactly able to figure out what it is?  I am not exactly clear about what CMakeLists.txt does in the first place.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/365633/unable-to-build-turtlebot3-package-from-source-using-catkin-build/) by [skpro19](https://answers.ros.org/users/36053/skpro19/) on ROS Answers with karma: 310 on 2020-11-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was able to resolve the issue using this [answer](https://answers.ros.org/question/252478/how-to-build-a-package-from-source-on-ubuntu-mate-1604-lts-and-ros-kinetic/?answer=252502#post-id-252502).

---

Originally posted by [skpro19](https://answers.ros.org/users/36053/skpro19/) with karma: 310 on 2020-11-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0